# change previous commit message after squash, not pushed

Tags: git, rebase

My scenario: I tried squashing 3 commits, the messages from 2 got combined with the last commit before branching, I want to remove the dummy commit messages.

(Sorry the samples below aren't direct copies from the terminal, just my interpretations.)

I had 7 commits in a row. 3 of them were ones I wanted to squash before merging my branch back into master.

```
af7d12c31e123023425a7b6f88bd3d6f43103358 dummy commit 3
69ec87cf490313086627df5224a1bcdbd3e9addd KEEP THIS COMMIT 4
fd6c843d59451c017628d03f3b4674045f06e54a KEEP THIS COMMIT 3
9ec44b48384373cbc8571b6beba7fd094db03e93 KEEP THIS COMMIT 2
53b8a217a4dcc85fb74e7c57861253f801ff882a KEEP THIS COMMIT 1
914dc32f7882b2b459e46b35a9314aef1c6824ba dummy commit 2
290f261f9d1541967f491fe8cba0fdd085ad5c20 dummy commit 1 (1st one in branch)
98dfb5299b122e496aeae29142038894488f0871 LAST COMMIT BEFORE BRANCHING
```

I ran

```
git rebase --interactive 98dfb5299b122e496aeae29142038894488f0871
```

I then set the 3 dummy commits (1,2,3) to squash. Saved and rebase finished.

Now when I "git log", the commit message for 98dfb5299b122e496aeae29142038894488f0871 looks like:

```
commit 98dfb5299b122e496aeae29142038894488f0871
Author: <me>
Date:   Thu Apr 25 14:51:28 2013 -0700

    LAST COMMIT BEFORE BRANCHING

    dummy commit 1

    dummy commit 2
```

I ran git rebase again from the same commit, 98dfb5299b122e496aeae29142038894488f0871, and changed that commit to "reword" and changed the message but it didn't have any effect.

I have not pushed any of these changes yet, just committed locally on my branch.

Do I need to rebase *again* but from the parent of LAST COMMIT BEFORE BRANCHING?

Comment: Your process is correct. Did you try to change the commit messages in the rebase list or in the commit msg editor that comes up during the commit? You can avoid this problem in the future by using `fixup` instead of `squash`. Fixup will discard the commit messages of the dummy commits.

Comment: In the commit message editor. That was the only editor that popped up the 2nd time around. The first time through, it opened in vim instead of nano like I normally use. I think I messed something up trying to get out of vim. Should I do the entire process again but use the parent of LAST COMMIT BEFORE BRANCHING? I'm afraid to do that since that's from a previous branch.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure why but I just redid it 2 more times and this time the changes have stuck.

Comment: Is the commit `98dfb52` where you branched off of from `master`?  In other words, is that commit in `master`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, a few notes:

- if `98dfb529` was the last commit before branching (that is, it appeared both in master and in your branch), then setting the first and second commits of your branch as "squash" (`290f261f` and `914dc32f`) effectively moved the branching point one step before. This is because `98dfb529` does not exist anymore in your branch, and it has been replaced by a squashed `98dfb529` + `290f261f` + `914dc32f` (let's call it `aaaaaaaa`). `98dfb529`, however, still exists in master.
- Then you decided to do the `reword` on `aaaaaaaa`. You changed the commit message. This change triggered a change in the commit hash itself, so now your branch contains `bbbbbbbb` instead of `aaaaaaaa`. `aaaaaaaa`, however, still exists around, even if it is not directly referenced by any branch: it will be deleted the next time that git triggers a garbage collection of dangling commits. Therefore, a `git log aaaaaaaa` will still show you the old message.

To recap, this is probably your current situation:

```
                          (..your branch..)
                          |
                          * af7d12c3  // Note however that these five commits
                          * 69ec87cf  // have now a different hash, because
                          * fd6c843d  // the history has been changed: when
(..master..)              * 9ec44b48  // the parent of a commit changes, then
|                         * 53b8a217  // the child's hash changes as well.
* 98dfb529   * aaaaaaaa   * bbbbbbbb
|            |            |
| __________/____________/
|/
(... previous history ...)
```